# I am having a problem with a recurring function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, if-statement

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 217, in <module>
    prompt()
  File "main.py", line 83, in prompt
    prompt()
TypeError: 'str'
```

This is the error I am getting after typing this code:

```
def prompt():
  print("What would you like to do?")
  prompt = input("")
  if prompt.upper() == "M":
    maps()
    prompt()
  elif prompt.upper() == "D":
    print("You go down.")
    spc()
    prompt()
  elif prompt.upper() == "U":
    print("You go up.")
    spc()
    prompt()
  elif prompt.upper() == "L":
    print("You go left.")
    spc()
    prompt()
  elif prompt.upper() == "R":
    print("You go right.")
    spc()
    prompt()
  else:
    print("You cannot do that.")
    spc()
    prompt()
```

and yes I know there is no current way to get out of the loop but I am working on that, I do not know if that is the problem hopefully it is not. If anybody has a solution I am open to most code. Though I only have around a year of experience so nothing extremely complicated. Thank you!

Comment: why is your `function` name and `variable` name same?

Comment: Try different names for fn ad variable

Answer (score 0):

You can change either the name of the function `prompt` or the name of the variable `prompt`. On doing so your problem will be solved.

```
def prmpt():
  print("What would you like to do?")
  prompt = input("")
  if prompt.upper() == "M":
    maps()
    prmpt()
  elif prompt.upper() == "D":
    print("You go down.")
    spc()
    prmpt()
  elif prompt.upper() == "U":
    print("You go up.")
    spc()
    prmpt()
  elif prompt.upper() == "L":
    print("You go left.")
    spc()
    prmpt()
  elif prompt.upper() == "R":
    print("You go right.")
    spc()
    prmpt()
  else:
    print("You cannot do that.")
    spc()
    prmpt()
```